# changing path of storage folder to public_html folder in domain

Tags: php, laravel

I can't store images in public_html location, because it shows me this path of storage:

> /home/gehops/domains/anyweb.com/laravel/public_html/images/

How should i change it to:

> /home/gehops/domains/anyweb.com/public_html/images/
>   ?

I've tried using symlink, but domain doesn't allow it. I have tried changing paths but all of them are using laravel folder instead of public_html folder.

Comment: Laravel doesn't have a `public_html` folder. To make your changes install Laravel into your `anyweb.com` folder and not into the `laravel` subfolder

Comment: You can change path of app_url in .env file.

Comment: when you upload laravel to domain you change public folder to public_html thats why you need to setup paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Root index.php after loading auotoload and app.php bind your public path as shown  below according to your folder

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use laravel-mix to copy the files in storage folder to 'app/public' folder. Then you can access to public folder by using "url()" method: